# Git using username@computername.localdomain as user.email in a WSL 2 envoronment

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using WSL 2 in a Windows 10 build 18985.1 machine.

I have already configured `user.name` and `user.email` as usual.

```sh
$ git config --global --list
user.name=João Antonio Santana
user.mail=joaosantana@outlook.com
```

When commiting, however, Git is showing this message:

```sh
$ git commit -m "commit inicial"
[master (root-commit) 5f3fcd5] commit inicial
 Committer: João Antonio Santana <joaos@DESKTOP-DNPG26L.localdomain>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 curriculo.tex
```

`git log`show this email entry:

```sh
$ git log
commit 5f3fcd5f80ee0053636f706c0242f7f27f681aa5 (HEAD -> master)
Author: João Antonio Santana <joaos@DESKTOP-DNPG26L.localdomain>
Date:   Sun Sep 22 13:56:45 2019 -0300

    commit inicial
```

Why is Git ignoring `.gitconfig` setting for `user.email`, and how to get rid of this?

Comment: `user.mail` != `user.email`.

Comment: @tkausl oh my... It passed me by and I didn't realize my mistake. Thank you. If you put it as an answer, I'll be more than happy to mark it right now.